# sql server change foreign key to contraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys

I currently have a main table, `tbl_o`, that is used to generate unique keys, along with a reference for what the key is used for.

```
[ObjectKey] [int] IDENTITY(-2147483648,1) NOT NULL,
[Record_Created_UTC] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[Primary_ObjectClassKey] [tinyint] NOT NULL
```

I currently have a sub table for each of the Primary_ObjectClassKey (e.g. `tbl_o_Avaya_Queue`), and use this table as the Foreign key relation, or a constraint to the table which holds the data.

e.g. Foreign key is:

```
[Avaya_PhoneQueue_ObjectKey] [int] NOT NULL,
```

This requires that when I create a key in the main table, I have to copy that key to the sub table (manually).
Hopefully, this diagram will help visualise the structure I have inherited.
[image: diagram to show cuuent setup]

Is there a way I can take out the sub tables and define the Foreign Key using a sub query of the main table, so the foreign key or contraint is defined as `Select ObjectKey from tbl_o where Primary_ObjectClassKey=xxx` ?

Comment: I am sure this is very clear to you but from what you posted it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @SeanLange, hopefully the diagram and extra text will help defining the issue

Comment: Why don't you tell us what's your end goal? It seems as this may only be a fraction of the end result. Technically speaking, why would you store the FK information in a table in the first place? SQL server allows you to store additional information. It has an objectProperty called 'Description'.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of a manual process of copying a key to another table, and the extra *19* tables that add a layer of complexity to the process.

Comment: I believe there is no way to do exactly what you want (define a fk with a query), but the path of least resistance to solve your incovenience may be a simple trigger on tbl_o which copies the ObjectKey to the proper table(s).